# show javascript alert from controller's action in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, alert

Is it possible to show a javascript alert message from controller's action in asp.net mvc(C#)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass a variable to the view. If it exists or is set to true, execute your javascript...

Comment: I have used json to call the action and execute the javascript.

Answer (score 1):

No, controller actions are executed on the server side. Wheras Javascript is executed on the client side.